# JupyterNotebook Kernel connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I tried to use the **Jupyter Notebook** application as usual but, I could not connect to the Kernel ( python(base) ) when I launched the the **jupyter notebook from my CMD** line,the notebook launched fine but it was impossible to execute any code since it **couldn’t connect to the kernel**.

But when I **launch the jupyter notebook from the anaconda navigator**, it works well and connects to the kernel.
I have looked at documentation and all the threads that I could find but nothing solved my solution of connecting with the kernel. I tried downgrading tornado, re-installing everything but it did not work. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what i am doing wrong.

The below screenshot shows, the jupyter notebook launched from anaconda navigator and the kernel was connected:

[image: The below screenshot shows, the jupyter notebook launched from anaconda navigator and the kernel was connected:]

The below screenshots show the jupyter notebook was launched from the cmd, and the connection to the kernel was not established:

[image: The below screenshots show the jupyter notebook was launched from the cmd, and the connection to the kernel was not established:]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try writing `conda` if it shows you an error then you should check whether conda path variable is added or you will need to run this jupyter notebook in anaconda prompt.

Comment: The path and everything is correct! I am using it daily with command line. `jupyter notebook` . But today when i used the same, the jupyter notebook opened as expected, but the kernel didn't connect. So my problem is not with opening the jupyter notebook, but the problem is in connection of kernel !